# Best approach to dynamically assign values to variables?

Tags: python

I have some set of states.

my currently code:

```
STATE_0, STATE_1, STATE_3, STATE_4, STATE_5 = range(5)
```

Each time I need to add state, I have to do two things: change state and change range.
This is error-prone. So I wrote this code to minimize it. Is this the best approach?
Of course, I can create a dictionary or some other structure, but I think it will not be a "pythonic way" and not the shortest way.

```
STATE_0, STATE_1, STATE_3, STATE_4, STATE_5, *_ = range(1000)
```

Comment: `states = {f'...{i}...': i for i in range(1000)}` isn't short enough?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the [enum module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) like this:

```
from enum import IntEnum, auto
class State(IntEnum):
    ZERO = auto()
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()
```

Using auto will automatically assign the next value so you can just keep adding states easily. And you can use it as with `State.Zero`.

Comment: Thank you, I am not familiar with this structure, I will learn more about it, but it requires import, which is not very good

Comment: True, it does require an import, but enum is part of the standard library so not additional installation is required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but my first reaction is to store `STATEn` as a list:

```
n = 1000
STATE = list(range(n))
```

and then to get indvidual states, you address them by index, e.g.

```
STATE[3]
```